# Edit Typoscript Setup of page in Extbase controller

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, extbase

I am currently working on an extbase extension. In that extension I want to edit/(add) the typoscript setup of a specific page from inside the extension controller. I have already aquired the uid of that page but I can't figure out how to access the typoscript setup of that page. Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in a meaningful way.

Extbase Controller Actions are usually executed long after the TypoScript setup has been evaluated and is in the middle of being processed.

What is it you're trying to modify in the setup exactly? There might be better/other ways.

Comment: I am trying to write an extension that generates pages with parameters submitted in a backend module. So far I have managed to create a page with a title submitted from the backend module. Now I want to automatically add a fluid-template to the page that I have just created with my extension. That's why I wanted to edit the typoscript setup. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: you might add this important information to your question, otherwise it could be misunderstood in the way that you want to change the typoscript of the currently rendered page (which is not possible as Nitori already mentioned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new page you also can create other records which belong into that page.
Each page can have it's own typoscript with an 'extension template' (a `sys_template` record) which is stored in that page (`pid` of sys_template record = `uid` of pages record). 'Extension templates' are additions to a global typoscript/ or at least the typoscript from the parent page.  In this 'extension template' you can assign just another fluid template.

If you don't know which fields needs to be filled in the correct way (primarily you need `pid` and `config`) create such an 'extension template' by hand and inspect the record in your database.